# assigning a count of 0 to a row with no data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to get a 0 count in my rows.

I have 2 very simple and very poorly designed tables like the ones below.

Unfortunately, I can't change them, and just have to work with them.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#CityList') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #CityList
CREATE TABLE #CityList ( CityName varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY )
INSERT INTO #CityList VALUES ('New York City'), ('Cairo'), ('London'), ('Tokyo')


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#A_LogFile') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #A_LogFile
CREATE TABLE #A_LogFile(PersonName varchar(255), CityName varchar(255))
INSERT INTO #A_LogFile VALUES 
    ('Joe', 'New York City'), ('Tim', 'Cairo'), ('Nancy','London'), ('Bilbo','Tokyo'),
    ('Joe', 'New York City'), ('Tim', 'Cairo'), ('Nancy','Tokyo'), ('Bilbo','New York City'),
    ('Joe', 'Cairo'), ('Tim', 'Cairo'), ('Nancy','Cairo'), ('Bilbo','Tokyo'),
    ('Joe', 'New York City'), ('Tim', 'Cairo'), ('Nancy','New York City'), ('Bilbo','Tokyo')
```

Ive tried various queries like this one:

```
select l.PersonName, cl.CityName, COUNT(l.cityName) AS 'Total Visits' 
from #CityList cl
left join #A_LogFile l on cl.CityName = l.CityName
group by l.PersonName, cl.CityName
order by PersonName, CityName
```

But I can never get that count of 0.

I need a row for each person with each city, and the count for that city even if that row doesn't exist in the #A_LogFile table.

Basically, I need the results to look like this(for the above sample data):

```
Bilbo    | Cairo          | 0
Bilbo    | London         | 0
Bilbo    | New York City  | 1
Bilbo    | Tokyo          | 3
Joe      | Cario          | 1
Joe      | London         | 0
Joe      | New York City  | 3
Joe      | Tokyo          | 0
Nancy    | Cairo          | 1
Nancy    | London         | 1
Nancy    | New York City  | 1
Nancy    | Tokyo          | 1
Tim      | Cairo          | 4
Tim      | London         | 0
Tim      | New York City  | 0
Tim      | Tokyo          | 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: this breaks the left group by l.PersonName

Comment: @Frisbee if take PersonName out of the Group By, then I get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cross join the citylist to distinct personname in a cte and use that as your from and left join logfile

```
WITH    cte
AS (
    SELECT    *
    FROM    (SELECT CityName FROM #CityList) cl,
            (SELECT DISTINCT PersonName FROM #A_LogFile) pn
    )
SELECT  cte.PersonName,
        cte.CityName,
        COUNT(lf.cityName) AS 'Total Visits'
FROM    cte
        LEFT JOIN #A_LogFile lf ON cte.CityName = lf.CityName
                                    AND cte.PersonName = lf.PersonName
GROUP BY cte.PersonName,
        cte.CityName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select l1.PersonName, cl.cityName, COUNT(l2.CityName) AS 'Total Visits' 
  from      #A_LogFile l1
 cross join #CityList  cl 
  left join #A_LogFile l2
         on l2.CityName   = cl.cityName 
        and l2.PersonName = l1.PersonName  
 group by l1.PersonName, cl.cityName
 order by l1.PersonName, cl.cityName
```

Comment: It wasnt me, but on the bright side you did get one up vote :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to derive a distinct list of people, then cross join that against your list of cities and finally left join against your LogFile to get counts.

```
select people.PersonName, cl.CityName, COUNT(l2.cityName) AS 'Total Visits' 
    from (select distinct l.PersonName from #A_LogFile l) people
        cross join #CityList cl
        left join #A_LogFile l2
            on people.PersonName = l2.PersonName
                and cl.CityName = l2.CityName
    group by people.PersonName, cl.CityName 
    order by PersonName, CityName;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're stuck with an older version of SQL that does not have CTE functionality, you can also use CROSS APPLY to map every city to every person, and then a sub-query to get the count:

`SELECT 
    l.PersonName, 
    cl.CityName, 
        COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(1)
        FROM #CityList cl2
            LEFT JOIN #A_LogFile l2
                ON cl2.CityName = l2.CityName
        WHERE cl2.cityName = cl.CityName
            AND l2.PersonName = l.PersonName
        GROUP BY l2.PersonName, cl2.CityName
        ), 0)
    AS 'Total Visits' 
FROM #A_LogFile l 
    CROSS APPLY #CityList cl
GROUP BY l.PersonName, cl.CityName
ORDER BY PersonName, CityName`